# JavaScript onkeydown / addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

I don't know if this has been answered somewhere, but here it goes.

Why is this working?

```
el.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) || e.keyCode == 8)) {
     return false;
  }
}
```

And this one not?

```
function negativeNum(e) {
  if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) || e.keyCode == 8)) {
    return false;
  }
}

el.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
  negativeNum(event);
}, false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `event` argument passed to `negativeNum` in the anonymous function is not defined anywhere, add it to the argument list of the anonymous function too.

Answer (score 5):

It should work if you pass the callback argument to your function like this

```
el.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
   negativeNum(event);
}, false);
```

you can user your function as callback function like this:

```
 el.addEventListener('keydown', negativeNum, false);
```

Comment: Or pass `negativeNum` directly to `addEventListener`.
`el.addEventListener("keydown", negativeNum, false)`

Comment: ah yea its even better

Answer (score 0):

```
function negativeNum(e) {
  if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) || e.keyCode == 8)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}


el.addEventListener('keydown', negativeNum, false);
```

more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609537/addeventlistenerkeydown-handlekeydown-false-vs-onkeydown-working-different)

Answer (score 0):

[1] `el.onkeydown = function (e) {}`

an HTML object has a different event attached to it as its keys, by default `el.onkeydown` was null & later we had overwritten it by an fn, the fn here can return `true` / `false`

if you return `false` it's basically doing 3 things:

```
[A] event.preventDefault();
[B] event.stopPropagation();
[C] stops execution and returns immediately
```

---

[2] `el.addEventListener('keydown', function () {})`

Deep down in `__proto__` of an HTML object, you can find `addEventListener` which takes a callback fn as the second param.

If you return anything from this `callback` fn the `return` value will be collected by the parent fn ie. `addEventListener` & will have no such effect as in [1].